# Ctrl highlights my cursor - Linux Mint 21

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint, keyboard-layout

When I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and I release it:

[image: how the highlight looks],

It highlights my cursor and I don't want that.  I can't find its name on the internet and don't know what to search for in dconf editor.

This makes gaming e.g. csgo (crouching) not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

According to [LinuxMint forum](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=333936), one solution is system settings > mouse and touchpad. A number of similar results from searching "linux mint control to highlight cursor" may also provide an answer.